# Unknown error the true part of if state dosen't work

Tags: javascript, html

I've write a code for simple pass and username form that will show up a content if u entered the user and password correct 
but it seems like there is a logical error on it that I can't find

```js
function show() {
  if (document.getElementById("user").value == "ahmed" && document.getElementById("pass").value == "ahmed") {
    document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pass1").style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else if (document.getElementById("user").value != "ahmed" && document.getElementById("pass").value != "ahmed") {
    alert("Password and username is incorrect")
  } else if (document.getElementById("pass").value != "ahmed") {
    alert("Password is incorrect");
  } else if (document.getElementById("user").value != "ahmed") {
    alert("Username is incorrect")
  }
}
```

The function work when I entered a wrong pass or username but when I entered them right nothing oth this code , the page just refresh automatically

```js
document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById("pass1").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

[source](http://www.mediafire.com/download/y19qx8qsdlmz5b6/PROJECT.HTML)

Comment: why its tagged in css

Comment: can you share some html

Comment: Please put a snippet man so we can help more quickly

Comment: mm mit will be shown without photos bcuz the photos is on my computer

Comment: What is this pure html with a submit button? or Aspx page with postback ? at least type some html so that someone can help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a fiddle and it is working fine

I don't know why it is not working for you. look at the fiddle

https://jsbin.com/vezito/edit?html,js,output

```
function show() {
  var content = document.getElementById("content");
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var pass = document.getElementById("pass");

  if (name.value == "ahmed" && pass.value == "ahmed") {

    document.getElementById("content").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("pass").style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else if (name.value != "ahmed" && pass.value != "ahmed") {
    alert("Password and username is incorrect");
  } else if (pass.value != "ahmed") {
    alert("Password is incorrect");
  } else if (name.value != "ahmed") {
    alert("Username is incorrect");
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't know i tried your fiddle and it's working
but doesn't work with me

Comment: and i don't know why the page is refreshing when i entered the user and pass

Comment: it is because input fields are inside form and when you hit a button from inside form it tries to post the form, I removed the form and now it does not refresh on show button click